# Rebuild start.sh

Tags: centos, expect

Can someone recode this start.sh script based on CentOS?
Its now based on Ubuntu

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
lassign $argv pssword port mod map num hostname rconpassword slots
spawn-fcgi su - et -c cd et -c "./etded.x86 +set s_num=$num +set net_port $port +set dedicated 2 +set fs_game $mod +set logfile 0 +set sv_punkbuster 0 +set sv_hostname \'$hostname\' +set rconpassword $rcon +set g_password '$password' +set sv_maxclients $slots +set map $map"
> /dev/null 2>&1 &
expect "Password:" { send "$pssword\r" }
expect "# " { send "q" }
exit
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of this script on Centos, and why it does not run?

Comment: [root@localhost host]# ./et_start.sh
invalid command name "lassign"
    while executing
"lassign $argv pssword port mod map num hostname rconpassword slots"
    (file "./et_start.sh" line 2)

Answer (score 0):

Your expect is probably built on Tcl 8.4, so change

```
lassign $argv pssword port mod map num hostname rconpassword slots
```

to

```
foreach {pssword port mod map num hostname rconpassword slots} $argv {break}
```

Comment: [host@localhost ~]$ ./et_start.sh
can't read "num": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn-fcgi su - et -c cd et -c "./etded.x86 +set s_num=$num +set net_port $port +set dedicated 2 +set fs_game $mod +set logfile 0 +set sv_punkbuster 0..."
    (file "./et_start.sh" line 3)

Comment: This is a Tcl syntax issue. Change the double quotes to braces (`{}`). If you're having further syntax errors, check the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).